# Understanding this function on IDA to get right amount of arguments

Tags: assembly, ida

I need help understanding this function (sub_59E1F0), this is the function itself:

```
sub_59E1F0 proc near

var_50C= dword ptr -50Ch
var_508= dword ptr -508h
var_504= dword ptr -504h
var_500= dword ptr -500h
var_4FC= dword ptr -4FCh
var_4F8= dword ptr -4F8h
var_4F4= dword ptr -4F4h
var_4F0= dword ptr -4F0h
var_4EC= dword ptr -4ECh
var_4E8= dword ptr -4E8h
var_4E4= dword ptr -4E4h
var_4E0= dword ptr -4E0h
var_4CD= byte ptr -4CDh
var_224= dword ptr -224h
var_21B= byte ptr -21Bh
var_1F4= dword ptr -1F4h
var_1C4= dword ptr -1C4h
alpha= dword ptr -18Ch
var_128= dword ptr -128h
var_124= dword ptr -124h
var_120= dword ptr -120h
var_C= dword ptr -0Ch
var_4= dword ptr -4
arg_0= dword ptr  4
arg_4= dword ptr  8
arg_8= dword ptr  0Ch
arg_C= dword ptr  10h
arg_10= dword ptr  14h
arg_14= dword ptr  18h
arg_18= byte ptr  1Ch

push    0FFFFFFFFh
push    offset loc_876A22
mov     eax, large fs:0
push    eax
mov     large fs:0, esp
sub     esp, 500h
mov     eax, [esp+50Ch+arg_10]
push    ebx
push    ebp
mov     ebp, [esp+514h+arg_4]
fld     dword ptr [eax]
fsub    flt_809F104
push    esi
push    edi
mov     edi, ebp
xor     ebx, ebx
sar     edi, 3
fstp    [esp+51Ch+var_4F8]
fld     dword ptr [eax+4]
fsub    flt_809F108
and     edi, 0Fh
fstp    [esp+51Ch+var_4F4]
fld     dword ptr [eax+8]
fsub    flt_809F10C
cmp     [esp+51Ch+arg_18], bl
fstp    [esp+51Ch+var_4F0]
jz      short loc_59E267
```

And then, this is a call to the function:

```
mov     edx, [esp+1Ch+var_10]
mov     ecx, [esp+1Ch+arg_1C]
and     edx, 0FFh
push    ebx
lea     eax, [esp+20h+var_C]
push    edx
mov     edx, [esp+24h+arg_18]
push    eax
push    ecx
push    edx
push    edi
push    23B5h
call    sub_59E1F0
add     esp, 1Ch
pop     edi
pop     esi
pop     ebx
add     esp, 10h
retn
```

I'm terrible at ASM, Debugging or reverse engineering.. but for what I can understand, there's supposed to be 7 arguments in the function, 6 of  which are DWORD (so some sort of number) and one is a BYTE so I assume that's probably a BOOL.

So I tried using the function like that, something like function(int, int, int, int, int, int, bool) or replacing int's for DWORDS or all for DWORDS, but it doesn't work (app crashes).

So I'm trying to hook the calls now, to see what is being actually send.. but I can't seem to catch the right amount of data as well..

I'm not an expert (obviously) but for what I can see on that example of a call to the function there's only 4 arguments, or maybe just 2? Maybe 2 arrays? (Because of the var_10, arg_1C, var_C and arg_18).

Could you guys help me understand what am I looking here? :)

---

Edit: This is what is next on the graph on IDA:

```
lea     eax, [esp+51Ch+var_508]
lea     ecx, [esp+51Ch+var_4F8]
push    eax
push    ecx
push    3D8F5C29h
jmp     short loc_59E276
```

//

```
loc_59E267:
lea     edx, [esp+51Ch+var_508]
lea     eax, [esp+51Ch+var_4F8]
push    edx
push    eax
push    3DCCCCCDh
```

//

```
loc_59E276:
push    offset flt_809F104
call    sub_6BC5EE
mov     esi, [esp+52Ch+arg_0]
mov     ecx, [esp+52Ch+arg_14]
add     esp, 10h
cmp     esi, 342h
jnz     short loc_59E2D8
```

Comment: `arg_10` is a pointer to at least 3 `float`s. You did not show the whole function so that's about all I can say.

Comment: Hey! Could you explain how you got that arg_10 is a pointer to 3 floats? :)

Comment: It's loaded into `eax` as `mov     eax, [esp+50Ch+arg_10]` then it's used as `fld dword ptr [eax]` and `+4` and `+8`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!